QuickFIX/J CipherSuites
I need to connect to a party which require these configurations:

Listing the cipher suites textually:

TLS_ECDHE_RSA_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_AES_128_CBC_SHA256

Are these QFJ Secure Communication Options ok?
SocketUseSSL=Y
SocketKeyStore=path_to_my_jks_file
SocketKeyStorePassword=my_password
EnabledProtocols=TLSv1.2
CipherSuites=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_AES_256_GCM_SHA384

Thanks a lot

QFJ uses the names as defined here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SunJSSEProvider
E.g. the suite you want to use should be
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384.

As a keyexchange in TLS, ECDH is not the same as ECDHE, and ECDH_RSA is very much not the same as ECDHE_RSA

@dave_thompson_085 thanks, typo fixed
